# Parse JSON dynamically and print key values on html with input checkbox and get a new JSON of selected keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to parse an unknown JSON whose format could be anything. So, I dont know the keys to access it. I want to access every key in JSON and print out all keys and values on screen using HTML. So I made a recursive function to access every key in JSON and used a variable name html to print the keys.
here`s the code:

JSON String:

```
{
    "FetchDetails": {
        "TransactionDetails": {
            "ServiceName": "Airtel Mobile Bill Postpaid",
            "officeID": "209",
            "BillAmount": "931.00",
            "ConsumerName": "Chetan Kumar Yadav",
            "consumerKeysValues": "9352423664",
            "partPaymentAllow": "1",
            "partPaymentType": "Both",
            "lookUpId": "6163298",
            "officeCodeValue": "RATNC011"
        },
        "BillDetails": [{
            "LableName": "Amount Before Due Date",
            "LableValue": "931.00"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Due Date",
            "LableValue": "NA"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Mobile Number",
            "LableValue": "9352423664"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Amount After Due Date",
            "LableValue": "931.00"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Bill Date",
            "LableValue": "NA"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Consumer Name",
            "LableValue": "Chetan Kumar Yadav"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Bill Cycle",
            "LableValue": "NA"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Bill Number",
            "LableValue": "NA"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Account Number",
            "LableValue": "1116231291"
        }]
    }
}
```

Heres the code to access every key in Parsed JSON

```
function scan(info) {
  var sub_root = [];
  if (info instanceof Object) {
    for (k in info) {

      if (info.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        console.log('scanning property ' + k);

        if (info[k] instanceof Object) {
          me += "<div class='root'> <div class='sub_root'> <input class='node' name='sub_root[" + k + "]' value='" + k + "' type='checkbox' />" + k;
          console.log(k);
          counter++;
          scan(info[k]);
          me += "</div>";
          me += "</div>";
        } else {
          me += "<div class='json_check' ><input class='node' name='sub_root[" + y + "] [" + k + "]' value='" + k + "' type='checkbox' />" + k + ": " + info[k] + " </div>";
          scan(info[k]);
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('found value : ' + info);

  }
}
```

After this, I am able to access every key in JSON and printed every node in a nested form with checkboxes in front of them to select any node/key.
Here`s the screenshot: 
[image: Fetched JSON keys and printed using HTML]

**[PROBLEM to be solved]**
Now at the bottom, I have a submit button, when I click on it I want to form a JSON of checked values with their parent nodes. So like if I check a key with a value, I should get its parent keys along with it.
For example: I have selected ServiceName and officeID in TransactionDetails, and some array values in BillDetails, so I should get something like this

```
{
    "FetchDetails": {
        "TransactionDetails": {
            "ServiceName": "Airtel Mobile Bill Postpaid",
            "officeID": "209"
        },
        "BillDetails": [{
            "LableName": "Amount Before Due Date",
            "LableValue": "931.00"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Due Date",
            "LableValue": "NA"
        }, {
            "LableName": "Account Number",
            "LableValue": "1116231291"
        }]
    }
}
```

**[EDITED]**
To get this JSON format and traverse through HTML objects I am writing this code:

```
$('#btn_createservice').on('click', function() {

        var solid = '{';
        var input = $('input').is(':checked');
        if(input){
            input = $('input');
        }

        $('.node:checked').each(function(index) {
            var parentEls = $(this).closest(input)
              .map(function() {
                  solid +=  this.value;
                return this.value;
              })
              .get()
              .join( ", " );

            console.log(parentEls);

        });
        solid += '}';

        $( ".submit_json" ).html(solid);
});
```

Comment: What problem are you having? You should be able to get all the container elements using `$(this).parents(".node")`. Then you can get the JSON keys from the `name` attribute. Actually, I recomment putting them into `data-*` attributes, so you don't have to parse the name.

Comment: @Barmar I am not able to get the JSON format for my checked keys. I am getting elements using `$(this).closest()`. I get the elements with their parent nodes but not able to figure out JSON format.

Comment: Post your code so we can help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you. But you need to use `.parents()` rather than `.closest()` so you get all the containers. Then loop over them to create nested objects.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited the question in which I have provided my code to get the parent nodes

Comment: What is `length`?

Comment: @Barmar I have updated it again, ignore the `length`.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by concatenating strings. Create objects and use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153675/discussion-between-sara-methuz-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.parents()`, not `.closest()` so you get all the containing elements.

Then create containing properties with those names when necessary.

```
$("#btn_createservice").on("click", function() {
    var svc_obj = {};
    $(".node:checked").each(function() {
        var cur_obj = svc_obj;
        $(this).parents(".node").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().reverse().forEach(function(name) {
            if (!cur_obj[name]) { // create property if it doesn't already exist
                cur_obj[name] = {};
            }
            cur_obj = cur_obj[name]; // use this for next iteration;
        });
        var thisname = this.name.match(/\[([^[])+\]$/)[1]; // Get property name from name="sub_root[...]"
        cur_obj[thisname] = this.value;
    });
    $(".submit_json").html(JSON.stringify(svc_obj));
})
```

You need to fix the HTML you're creating so that the checkboxes have `value='" + info[k] "'`.